# Fetch as Google for app 'Internal error' for language other than English

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-search, google-search-platform

My android app is developed with Xamarin Android for Visual Studio 2015 SP2. It is published in Google Play and is operating successfully for half a year.

Now I try to apply Google search indexing to my app and bind it to my website.

I created an APK with Intent filter applied and try to test it in the `Search Console` with the `Fetch as Google` tool.

With the blank app URI and language set to English I can successfully fetch the main page of my app.

```
Partial
Fetched with some missing resources. Learn more

APK version: Local upload - ru.noxx.polyglot16-Sig... [5/13/16, 9:40 AM]

Fetched URI: android-app://ru.noxx.polyglot16/
Date: 5/13/16 9:40 AM
Language: English
Googlebot type: Google for android apps
```

The problem is when I change the language to Russian I get the dreadful 'internal error':

```
Internal error
The page could not be fetched due to an internal Google error.

APK version: Local upload - ru.noxx.polyglot16-Sig... [5/13/16, 9:40 AM]

Fetched URI: android-app://ru.noxx.polyglot16/
Date: 5/13/16 9:45 AM
Language: Russian
Googlebot type: Google for android apps
```

My app is not localized. It's primary language is Russian and it has no localizations to any other language and that is by design.

Should I worry about the error or should I just use English for the test purposes?

Comment: I am sad this is so old and with no answer :-(